# Retrieve date from from date-time datatype?

Tags: soql, date, datetime, salesforce-classic

Hi I want to get only date value from CreatedDate 
Example:

```
select id,name,createdDate from Account where DAY_IN_MONTH(createdDate) =: 12
```

Which retrieves account created on date 12.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

To get the Date portion from DateTime datatype as of CreatedDate, you need to use `DAY_ONLY()` function as follows

```
Date dt = Date.newInstance(2017, 6, 20);
List<Account> acct = [select id,name,createdDate 
                     from Account 
                     where DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) =:dt];
```

Refer [Date functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm)

Comment: Hi thanks, but i want date portion when only number is provided.

Comment: can you provide an example of data amending your question

Comment: For example: if a user provides 30,  query should works as                                                       
select id,name,createdDate from Account where DAY_ONLY(createdDate) =: 30

Comment: what you are expecting to return?

Comment: Created Account on that date.

Comment: what about the month part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61009/discussion-between-effat-naaz-and-santanu-boral).

Comment: is that solved your requirement?